# square root of a binary number and beyond

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how to find (efficiently) binary expansion of a square root of a number which is given as a binary number. Is  there any general method to find the n-nary expansion of m-th root of a number which is given in its n-nary expansion.
I hope n-nary is the term used to say a number is represented in the base n.

Comment: The Newton method (a common way to calculate square roots) is base-agnostic. So it reduces your problem to calculating +, -, * and / in base $n$.

Comment: do this method will work even in binary number setup?

Comment: Sure, there's nothing special about base 10.

Comment: by Newton's method, you mean Newton Raphson method?

Comment: Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Square_root_of_a_number

Comment: ya. thanks. but how to use number in base other than ten?

Answer (score 2):

Either use a numerical method (like Newton's) to solve $x^n - a = 0$ (starting points could be estimated roughly, or given by a table), or use a [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) algorithm for digit-by-digit computation. Newton himself used the binomial expansion of $(1 + x)^{1/2}$ judiciously.

If you have the luxury of being able to precompute, a table and interpolation could serve. Or perhaps cook up a polynomial or rational approximation for the range of interest.

In either case range reducing transformations (e.g. reduce $\sin$ to the range 0 to $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ by periodicity and other equivalences, or e.g. $\sqrt{8} = 2 \sqrt{2}$) should be applied first.

Comment: cordic algorithm is interesting. thanks. can you explain me Newton's method little more clearly.

Comment: @GArunkumar, look it up in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), they explain it much better than I could.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number

Comment: in this page I could not find. is this the page you mean?